# laravel - Radio button/checkbox passing the wrong value to the database

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm creating a survey website, after creating a new survey and choose question type and add question and options. I want to check if I take the survey all the answer will be stored in the database. I tried it but the problem was any answers to question (with Radio button/checkbox type) the value that been stored in the database is "on". 
The text/textarea was stored correctly. But couldn't figure out how I can fix it. No matter what I choose the value will be "on".

This is my answerController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Survey;
use App\Answer;
use App\Http\Requests;


class AnswerController extends Controller
{

  public function store(Request $request, Survey $survey)
  {
    // remove the token
    $arr = $request->except('_token');
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
      $newAnswer = new Answer();
      if (! is_array( $value )) {
        $newValue = $value['answer'];
      } else {
        $newValue = json_encode($value['answer']);
      }
      $newAnswer->answer = $newValue;
      $newAnswer->question_id = $key;
      $newAnswer->survey_id = $survey->id;

      $newAnswer->save();

      $answerArray[] = $newAnswer;
    };
    return redirect()->action('SurveyController@view_survey_answers', [$survey->id]);
  }
}
```

This is the answer Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Answer extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['answer'];
  protected $table = 'answers';

  public function survey() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
  }

  public function question() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
  }
}
```

This is the code to create the question and chooses type:

```
@extends('master')
@section('title', 'Survey')

@section('content')
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
    <span class="card-title"> {{ $survey->title }}</span>
    <p>
      {{ $survey->description }}
    </p>
    <br/>
    <a href='view/{{$survey->id}}'>Take Survey</a> | <a href="{{$survey->id}}/edit">Edit Survey</a> | <a href="/survey/answers/{{$survey->id}}">View Answers</a> <a href="#doDelete" style="float:right;" class="modal-trigger red-text">Delete Survey</a>
    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <!-- TODO Fix the Delete aspect -->
    <div id="doDelete" class="modal bottom-sheet">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <h4>Are you sure?</h4>
            <p>Do you wish to delete this survey called "{{ $survey->title }}"?</p>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="/survey/{{ $survey->id }}/delete" class=" modal-action waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text">Yep yep!</a>
              <a class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light green white-text btn">No, stop!</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider" style="margin:20px 0px;"></div>
    <p class="flow-text center-align">Questions</p>
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable">
        @forelse ($survey->questions as $question)
        <li style="box-shadow:none;">
          <div class="collapsible-header">{{ $question->title }} <a href="/question/{{ $question->id }}/edit" style="float:right;">Edit</a></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div style="margin:5px; padding:10px;">
                {!! Form::open() !!}
                  @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                    {{ Form::text('title')}}
                  @elseif($question->question_type === 'textarea')
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                      <label for="textarea1">Provide answer</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  @elseif($question->question_type === 'radio')

                    @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                      <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{ $key }}" />
                        <label for="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                      </p>
                    @endforeach
                  @elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')
                    @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                    <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $key }}" />
                      <label for="{{$key}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                    </p>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        @empty
          <span style="padding:10px;">Nothing to show. Add questions below.</span>
        @endforelse
    </ul>
    <h2 class="flow-text">Add Question</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ $survey->id }}/questions" id="boolean">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <select class="browser-default" name="question_type" id="question_type">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="textarea">Textarea</option>
            <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
            <option value="radio">Radio Buttons</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input name="title" id="title" type="text">
          <label for="title">Question</label>
        </div>
        <!-- this part will be chewed by script in init.js -->
        <span class="form-g"></span>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

And this is JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible({
    accordion: false
  });

  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();

  $(document).on('click', '.delete-option', function() {
    $(this).parent(".input-field").remove();
  });

  // will replace .form-g class when referenced
  var material = '<div class="input-field col input-g s12">' +
    '<input name="option_name[]" id="option_name[]" type="text">' +
    '<span style="float:right; cursor:pointer;"class="delete-option">Delete</span>' +
    '<label for="option_name">Options</label>' +
    '<span class="add-option" style="cursor:pointer;">Add Another</span>' +
    '</div>';

  // for adding new option
  $(document).on('click', '.add-option', function() {
    $(".form-g").append(material);
  });
  // allow for more options if radio or checkbox is enabled
  $(document).on('change', '#question_type', function() {
    var selected_option = $('#question_type :selected').val();
    if (selected_option === "radio" || selected_option === "checkbox") {
      $(".form-g").html(material);
    } else {
      $(".input-g").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

I followed a tutorial and he said :
At the moment, a typical answer submission might look like this:

```
{
  4: {
    answer: "My answer"
  },
  5: {
    answer: "on"
  },
  6: {
    answer: "on"
  }
}
```

So our function store() , the part, foreach ($arr as $key => $value) goes through the above JSON object, then the key will be, for example, 4, then the value will be the $value['answer']

In that way, we’re able to iterate and grab the key which refers to what question id, then the answer is stored in the $value['answer'].

---

^ 
But he didn't fix this problem.

So the Radio and Checkbox will be an array but the code didn't take the part the user choose from these arrays.
Do you have an idea to how can I change the AnswerController to tell the code take just the one the user choose?

This is the answerController that take care of the store part:

```
public function store(Request $request, Survey $survey)
  {
    // remove the token
    $arr = $request->except('_token');
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
      $newAnswer = new Answer();
      if (! is_array( $value )) {
        $newValue = $value['answer'];
      } else {
        $newValue = json_encode($value['answer']);
      }
      $newAnswer->answer = $newValue;
      $newAnswer->question_id = $key;
      $newAnswer->survey_id = $survey->id;

      $newAnswer->save();

      $answerArray[] = $newAnswer;
    };
    return redirect()->action('SurveyController@view_survey_answers', [$survey->id]);
  }
}
```

And this is the answer table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('question_id');
            $table->integer('survey_id');
            $table->string('answer');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: It would be much easier to answer your question if you only include the code which is relevant, ie: the code relating to the radio / checkboxes.

Comment: Hey first thing i notice is you dont have attribute name on radio button or checkbox, check that first